# Access dictionary value inside linq method

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I got the following structures:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var fooMapping = GetFooMapping();
var fooObjects = GetFoos();

fooObjects.All(foo =>
{
    Tuple<string, string> value = null;
    if (fooMapping.TryGetValue(foo.Code, out value))
    {
        foo.Description = value.Item1;
        foo.Name = value.Item2;
    };
    return true;
});
```

The GetFoos method returns an Enumerable of Foo objects that don't have all their properties set.

GetFooMapping returns an

```
IDictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>
```

where TKey = Foo.Code and TValue.Item1 = Foo.Description and TValue.Item2 = Foo.Name.

While debugging, after running through the last lines of code I see that some of the properties weren't set even though the Foo.Code exists in the dictionary.
Am I missing something?

Comment: what is your code to check that properties were set? if you are using fooObjects after fooObjects.All(...), then, i suppose, foos are enumerated again and you just get other objects. i would try var fooObjects = GetFoos().ToList();

Comment: Offtopic, but you're using `All` wrong. You should replace it with foreach.

Comment: Side note: using regular `foreach` will produce code that is easier to understand - usually you'd not change items while using LINQ methods, but rather create new once... Additionally it will fix the issue with "lazy execution" not performed when you expect it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `All` you could use `Select` and assign the result back to `fooObjects`

```
fooObjects = fooObjects.Select(foo =>
    {
        Tuple<string, string> value = null;
        if (fooMapping.TryGetValue(foo.Code, out value))
        {
            foo.Description = value.Item1;
            foo.Name = value.Item2;
        }
        return foo;
    });
```

The main issue that you are likely having is that `All` is iterating over an `IEnumerable` that is generating it's items.  Then the next time you iterate `fooObjects` it generates them again and the changes in `All` are lost.  Further this is not how Linq is meant to be used.  `All` is meant for checking a predicate over the collection, not for modifying or projecting.

The other option is to make sure you are working with a list and just use a `foreach`

```
var fooObjects = GetFoos().ToList();

foreach(var foo in fooObjects)
{
    Tuple<string, string> value = null;
    if (fooMapping.TryGetValue(foo.Code, out value))
    {
        foo.Description = value.Item1;
        foo.Name = value.Item2;
    }
}
```